# Writing a method to return a java Class constrained to a certain type in Scala

Tags: scala, types, parameterized

For example, I have this:

```
abstract class Vehicle

class Car extends Vehicle
```

And I want to write a method that returns a java Class, but constrained to only Classes of type Vehicle.

```
object CarDealer {
  def getVehicularClass: Class[Vehicle] = classOf[Car]
}
```

I am not able to get the following different approaches to work:

1. The way I would normally deal with this

   ```
   object CarDealer {
     def getVehicularClass[A <: Vehicle]: Class[A] = classOf[Car]
   }

   [error]  found   : java.lang.Class[Car](classOf[Car])
   [error]  required: Class[A]
   [error]   def getVehicularClass[A <: Vehicle]: Class[A] = classOf[Car]
   ```
2. Using an abstract type

   ```
   type V <: Vehicle
   ```
3. Using an implicit manifest (seems like it only constrains method arguments and not return values)

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Vehicle` is the supertype.  You don't know that some subtype `A` of `Vehicle` is going to include `Car`, so you can't write it generically that way.  What if someone asked for a `Bus`?  The `CarDealer` can't help, but the type signature promises that it can make it work for *any* `A <: Vehicle` that you ask for.

If you don't care about preserving the real type of the vehicle, just write

```
object CarDealer {
  def getVehicularClass: Class[Vehicle] = classOf[Car]
}
```

Alternatively, if you want some interface obeyed, you specify in the interface what you want:

```
trait VehicleClass[A <: Vehicle] {
  def getVehicularClass: Class[A]
}
```

and then you have your object state which subclass of vehicle it is promising to return:

```
object CarDealer extends VehicleClass[Car] {
  def getVehicularClass = classOf[Car]
}
```

and now all promises are specified and lived up to.

Comment: Your first solution does not compile... The second part is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The type `Class[T]` is invariant in type `T`. Thus even if `A extends B`, `classOf[A]` is not a subtype of `classOf[B]`. Therefore there's no exact solution to your problem...

Answer (score 0):

This constrain is adequately expressed with existential types:

```
object CarDealer {
  def getVehicularClass: Class[_ <: Vehicle] = classOf[Car]
}
```

Of course, there might be other requirements that make an existential type inappropriate, but your problem is not particularly well stated.